# configuration problem for png static images with jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

please find below my config with webpack and jest. have any one faced the same issue and knows how to resolve it ? thanks you in advance.
my webpack.config.js:
`const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        index: './src/index.js',
      },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
      },
    module: {
      
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                      presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
                    }
                },

            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
              test: /\.css$/,
              use: [
                'style-loader',
                {
                  loader: 'css-loader',
                  options: {
                    importLoaders: 1,
                    modules: true
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, 
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                name: './src/public/[name].[ext]'
              }
            }
        ]
    },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.html")
    })
  ]
};`
```

my jest.config.js:
`module.exports = { setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./setUpTests.js'], moduleNameMapper: { "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "/mock/fileMock.js", "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy" } };`

my fileMock.js:
`module.exports = 'test-file-stub';`

thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What issue you have faced, you're not clear enough.

Comment: I resolved this by adding a transform in my jest config: 
`module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./setUpTests.js'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  },
  transform: {
    "\\.jsx$": "babel-jest",
    "\\.js$": "babel-jest",
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "./fileTransformer.js"
  }
};`

Comment: @MaroueneSidhom You may want to add the solution that worked for you as an answer to your own question.